# Diff tool that can be integrated into a C# app

Tags: c#, diff

I have a small C# app and I'd like to provide the ability to preview diffs and accept changes. My inputs are only text files. I came across some tools like kdiff3 and winmerge and I was wondering if anyone's integrated them inside a C# app and if yes, how was it done? I also came across some nice projects on CodeProject from an earlier stackoverflow question but since those projects were written in 2004, I was wondering if you have any suggestions for an open source diff and merge tool that I can integrate? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked out csdiff ?

http://code.google.com/p/csdiff/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did look at their website right now, but I'd rather not have a diff tool which provides the output like the google diff merge tool. I'm looking for a library which can display the files side by side and colored appropriately, similar to what review board or winmerge provide.

Comment: @Rndm, is that google csdiff project what happened to the page gone, apache test page, http://www.componentsoftware.com/   , referenced on http://download.cnet.com/windows/componentsoftware/3260-20_4-54271-1.html ? I loved CSdiff so much, really want a replacement. I'm worried about the cnet one. Should I be?

Answer (score 7):

You might want to checkout [DiffPlex](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex). It is (amongst other things) a library that can be used to generate text diffs. It also provides some higher level classes that provide a more complete "diff model" that should be easier to use for rendering diffs in, say, a textbox.

Personally, I have only used it for minor tasks, but it looks powerful enough to handle more sophisticated scenarios as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try downloading DiffPlex and the interface as a diff tool does look good but it does not provide merging/patching

Comment: Oh, I missed that "and accept changes" in your question. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the DiffPlex reference! DiffPlex makes it extremely easy to compare strings and return a string that shows changes.

Answer (score 6):

Winmerge, as you mentioned, can be integrated with other apps [via the command line](http://manual.winmerge.org/Command_line.html).  Here's an [example of visual studio](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/) using these command line parameters to replace the built in diff client.  In regards to launching winmerge itself, I found [this simple example](http://omegacoder.com/?p=119) of how to call an external program from C#.