# How to compare two pieces of html code and show differences

Tags: c#, html

Lets suppose I have this 2 htmls

```
var p1 ="<h1>Title</h1>";
var p2 = "<h2>Title changed</h2>";
```

I need to generate an email with a visual difference, just something like what source control systems do with the content changed/added/deleted.

Basically the email needs to say what changed, what was added, what was deleted.

Obviosly the htmls will be more complex, I just wanted to illustrate what I  need to do.

However, I am not sure, at what direction should I look, what are my options?

Comment: Google `diff tool c#`

Comment: You may look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/any-decent-text-diff-merge-engine-for-net There are some links to diff tools that work with c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use John Resig's algorithm to compare two strings: http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Just download and include jsdiff.js in your script and run it like this:

```
var p1 ="<h1>Title</h1>";
var p2 = "<h2>Title changed</h2>";

document.body.innerHTML = diffString(p1, p2);
```

Comment: +1, looks a nice option to look at

Comment: just a small question, I am generating emails with the result, first 1. Can I have javascripts embedded on emails?, 2. Here we dont have exchange, but lotus notes, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: well, Lotus Notes supports some sort of javascript execution but take into account that many users set this feature off since it can be a security hole

Comment: DiffPlex is a better solution to compare 2 html pages: https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex and works well on C#

Answer (score -1):

Look into [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) . 
WinMerge is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows. WinMerge can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle.

Comment: Does that have an API suitable for consumption in C#? If so, please link to it, otherwise this answer should probably be a comment...

Comment: It is for  Manual Comparing only . For Automatic Comparing of Documents , you will have to write Code ..

Comment: You can also look into this SO thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505851/diff-tool-that-can-be-integrated-into-a-c-sharp-app

Comment: that was kind of my point! He is looking for a way to automate this process through `c#`, as that is what has tagged the question with.

Comment: OK .. i misunderstood the question then .. Anyway the Link has the Relevant Answers ..